# Unable to bind TS object with v-model in vue 3.3

Tags: vuejs3

I am trying to bind a Typescript object via `const filter = ref<Filter>();` which will be later used in my form.

Full script

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useStore } from "../../store/store";
import {Filter} from "../../lib/models/Filter";
import {ref} from "vue";

const store = useStore();
const filter = ref<Filter>();
//const Filter = defineModel<Filter>();

let updateFilter = () => {
    store.filter = filter.value;
    console.log("FIRED" + filter);
}

</script>
```

template snippet

```
<input id="spring" name="spring" type="checkbox" v-model="filter.spring" v-on:change="updateFilter"
 class="focus:ring-indigo-500 h-4 w-4 text-indigo-600 border-gray-300 rounded">
```

both `v-model="filter.spring"` and `v-model="filter.value?.spring"` do not work. By does not work I mean the word after filter is always red in the IDE and the browser doesn't render and reads with an error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')` or it cannot read `filter.spring`.

Looking at the [docs](https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-3-3) I am doing it correctly. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

[vue-play-ground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNrlVttu20YQ/ZUFX2yjoejaTlGotIIkdQAXvSHpW9mHJTmi1t5bd5eKVFX/3tldUqIoV3AeChSJHgTtXM7MzhyRZ5O81nqybCGZJrmtDNOOWHCtnhWSCa2MIxtiYE62ZG6UIGcYerZzvWPcgSHRVSSTLBo8XpEUspCVktYRYRty61HOz7oMqRyeZQ2GyebsopB5FotjWTw4EJpTB3giJI85WTwsvp5tNgFxu80zPPncXXzyInEWi85ZM3mwSuKtNj6tSColNONgftGOYVNFMiXB432Uc/Xxh2BzpoUXvb1aQPX4hP3BrrytSH41YMEs8bI7n6OmARfddx9+hhX+3jmFqluO0Sec78Eq3voeY9ibVtbY9iAudHsfFoDD+83erRxI21/KN+ojtyG+SHAVb09cfd/u9eQ65BVyi1PcL9IT42Af+0++uCIVp9beFslcSZeWitdEmPRbIkr8cnjBdMWLZNat/TXn5K1qjQWLu7saw80Z8BrZN7IHH4cG+bIrF6BLaoEMCpfpTaxZclo9Ytk3a/LhkWHRH2EJPM8iyFPwNVvusIVDHKtpBek6vUGY4/ijnDmHFWE4J5tanClO9F+yTmVWIP2UFunLk+kBgkndOsJqRCihYVJ6jhBJBRxa3Fp7S6ByqZC3ZJki04D70nHJg+hlquS0WlDZ+KRW17j0uDv/fz7VUPfZ06Fq7dT/u1Mma9ao9OXlJd7shnzsl9TZv0F7qQw+CtLG0HV6jWejkPVQ4xTyDGf13FEKnl5HbCt8LqclcCSIORzJAWUF1KwVpKKaOcrZXxABQitXl5cI02cifTzeqWZONHvS939hEvNZfiK49j2bRtZnMGqU8fmyanTRT2TWMPsLYBetl1RWfgE9swaWZ7BqEP35MmpwyU9kU5/53zDpKXueDd7YAxUWNNxQTBKOm/JvbRQfA2EZN9YpSy8f7/sdfrcPQtm4iwi6En29sIzEiNoy96uYMwk1+bsTprPzCwzOshjcaZBbEsN+8uTqtGUMLCQHR4ZkwuDzC3I76/WSB1IcJlw150Xy7v793fe4p6+6PjwGyqdDKWvdmgNBTarBC4/g9ib8jTKru/DEWZRZsAo3Dk+FOaqPvuOuOOq+V1OkIDZAEceb+lfTq+mBuWfCyDx83CCSbEUJ5vc/orNRY/BaVY8e+tDaVHpseqBLOrbhpsamoJQNB2vHHir+PALFJVCv746CRbs66sno6qia9n/qoRVXk2z/Abm67EI=)

Comment: Can you reproduce it on https://play.vuejs.org/ ?

Comment: @Dimava updated post with the link.

Comment: you are missing `v-if="filter"` on inputs so it crashes when filter is undefined

Comment: What you intend to do when filter is undefined?

Comment: @Dimava I removed it. It doesn't matter. It is selected or it is not.

Comment: Are you trying to make it `v-model`, `prop` or just a `ref`? In any case, you need to either make sure it's provided (`defineModel({required: true})`)  or has a default (`ref({})`, `{filter = {}} = defineProps()`, `defineModel({default: {}})`)

Comment: Dimava's comment about `default: {}` works for me, but also alternatively this works too: Use a v-if: `<MyComponent v-if="model" v-model="model" />`, where model is: `const model = defineModel()`. Either way seems to clear a similar Typescript warning for me and works in browser tests.